How to Downgrade nestjs/cli to a specific version
i just started to work with nestjs. the problem is when i want to add a module and use this command:
nest g module <module_name>
id get this error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:module --name=users --no-dry-run --no-skip-import --language="ts" --source-root="src" --spec --no-flat --spec-file-suffix="spec"
i searched and people were saying that downgrading the nestjs cli would solve the problem. but i do not know how to do that.
generate module
got error

nest g module <module_name> - that looks weird. Are you sure the brackets should be there? Or is this any other command than the one you're really using?

by <module_name> i meant my module name. the command would be like: nest g module User. i edited the question. actually i do not know how to install for example 8.0.0 version
